# Keras Sequential - ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_3 to have shape (None, 45) but got array with shape (2868700, 1)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to create a simple deep neural network using the keras API but i am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ali J/PycharmProjects/SPECOM/1dcnn_experiment.py", line 86, in <module>
    model.fit(trainX, trainY)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 960, in fit
    validation_steps=validation_steps)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1574, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1411, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='target')
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 153, in _standardize_input_data
    str(array.shape))
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_3 to have shape (None, 45) but got array with shape (2868700, 1)
```

this is my Python code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu', input_shape=trainX.shape[1:]))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(len(set(trainY)), activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(lr=1e-4), metrics=["accuracy"])
model.fit(trainX, trainY)

#trainX.shape = (2868700, 57)
#trainY.shape = (2868700,)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your targets (`trainY`) into categorical shape, meaning one-hot shape.

You can use this keras function:

```
keras.utils.to_categorical(y, num_classes=None)
```

> Converts a class vector (integers) to binary class matrix.
>
> E.g. for use with categorical_crossentropy.
>
> **Arguments**
>
> - y: class vector to be converted into a matrix (integers from 0 to    num_classes).
> - num_classes: total number of classes.
>
> **Returns**
>
> A binary matrix representation of the input.

[Link to the respective part of the Keras Documentation.](https://keras.io/utils/#to_categorical)